# How can I use Powershell to rename all files where the name has the format "digits [space] name with spaces" to "digits [hyphen] name with spaces"?

Tags: powershell, regex, rename, wildcards

I have a lot of files with names of the format "digits [space] name with spaces" or "(digits) [space] name with spaces" e.g.:

> 23 Filename 23 with spaces.txt
> (47) Filename 47 with spaces.txt

which are split across several directories, and I need them to be in the format "digits hyphen name with spaces" e.g.:

> 23-Filename 23 with spaces.txt
> 47-Filename 47 with spaces.txt

I've no problem with the command to find files recursively and then rename them when I have a fixed pattern:

```
get-childitem -filter "*pattern*" -recurse | rename-item -newname {$_.Name -replace "pattern", "new string"}
```

I'm struggling with the regex(?) or wildcards need to a) find the files and then, more importantly, b) do the update.

As long as the rename doesn't process files that don't match the pattern then part a) is less important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following cmdlets:

```ps
gci -Recurse -file | where { $_.Name -match '^\(?\d+\)? .+' } | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '^\(?(\d+)\)? (.+)' , '$1-$2' }
```